# Loop to insert rows to tables across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm working on a loop to go through a series of worksheets in my workbook and add a row (or two) to the table on that worksheet if the date associated with that worksheet is the same or after the selected date. I made a table with the sheet names, dates, and table names that the code could loop through ("Lists" referenced in the code). However, nothing happens when I run the code. Should I add a Do While statement or nest these differently?

```
Private Sub CmdBttn2_Click()
Dim TxtBxAddDate As Date 'Is this necessary?
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")


'Loop over list of sheets??
    Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 31 'loop through rows 1 to 31
        If TxtBxAddDate >= ws.Cells(i, 21).Value Then 'Compare date to date on sheet list in column U
        Sheets(ws.Cells(i, 20).Value).Select 'Find sheet name in column T
           If ChkBxLAC01 = True And ChkBxLAC02 = True Then 'Add to both modules
                 newrowA = Worksheets(ws.Cells(i, 20).Value).ListObjects(ws.Cells(i, 22).Value).ListRows.Add(2)  'Add row to table in sheet
                 With newrowA
                 'Add module 1 info to row 5
                    ws.Cells(5, 3).Value = "Yes" 'Enabled
                    ws.Cells(5, 4).Value = "1" 'Module 1
                    ws.Cells(5, 5).Value = TxtBxNewAnalyte 'Assay name
                 'Add module 2 info to row 6
                    ws.Cells(6, 3).Value = "Yes" 'Enabled
                    ws.Cells(6, 4).Value = "2" 'Module 2
                    ws.Cells(6, 5).Value = TxtBxNewAnalyte 'Assay name
                 End With
                 MsgBox TxtBxNewAnalyte & " added to modules 1 and 2.", vbOKOnly
              ElseIf ChkBxLAC01 = True And ChkBxLAC02 = False Then 'Add to module 1, not 2
                 newrowB = Worksheets(ws.Cells(i, 20).Value).ListObjects(ws.Cells(i, 22).Value).ListRows.Add(1)  'Add row to table in sheet
                 With newrowB
                    ws.Cells(5, 3).Value = "Yes" 'Enabled
                    ws.Cells(5, 4).Value = "1" 'Module 1
                    ws.Cells(5, 5).Value = TxtBxNewAnalyte 'Assay name
                 End With
                 MsgBox TxtBxNewAnalyte & " added to module 1.", vbOKOnly
              ElseIf ChkBxLAC01 = False And ChkBxLAC02 = True Then 'Add to module 2, not 1
                 newrowC = Worksheets(ws.Cells(i, 20).Value).ListObjects(ws.Cells(i, 22).Value).ListRows.Add(1)  'Add row to table in sheet
                 With newrowC
                    ws.Cells(5, 3).Value = "Yes" 'Enabled
                    ws.Cells(5, 4).Value = "2" 'Module 2
                    ws.Cells(5, 5).Value = TxtBxNewAnalyte 'Assay name
                 End With
                 MsgBox TxtBxNewAnalyte & " added to module 2.", vbOKOnly
              Else
              MsgBox "No modules selected!", vbExclamation
              GoTo NxtTbl
           End If
           Else
           GoTo NxtTbl
        End If
NxtTbl:
        Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Step through with `F8` to see the execution.

Comment: What sets the value of TxtBxAddDate?  I see the declaration but nothing seems to give it an initial value.

Comment: I think you should take this over to code review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  There's a lot of redundant code and some extraneous selects that could really be tightened up.  This will also help show where things are going wrong.

Comment: @RyanB. It fills with the current date when the form initializes. Thanks for the suggestion.